# PHP - Data Strucure to hold Matrix of Strings and Numeric Values

Tags: php, matrix, data-structures

I have following data structure needs to be hold in the memory for dynamic calculations on the fly, how do i create matrix data structure that hold this values in PHP ? (i presume i have to use multi-denominational array however i am unsure of how to use them in practical examples like this one below)

[image]

Any ideas on that ?Basically i am looking for Build in Matrix class like in the below link, in that case its a Binary Tree.

http://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/

Comment: any one else want to know what water mark he removed?

Comment: just use an array, no need for a table with that small data

Comment: ask a good question and i would: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mahen3d - don't bitch at other people for misusing the comments section if you're going to do it too. - make an array of data for each row, and then put all the arrays into another array.. what is the problem?

Comment: @Dagon shit or not will be determine by other people not you. if you dont like it downvote it and leave, asking about watermark and justifying it by saying programmers are curios is a joke.

Comment: Why shouldn't one hint at a possible violation of law? It could start a discussion if the question should be removed.

Comment: @Pamblam provide an example of how to use matrix with PHP, i thought there may be a better way of structuring matrix with its own data strucure built into PHP, whats wrong wiht asking that ?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone he is not hinting about violation of law, he just curios :D besides if its violates the law proof is better than hinting isnt it ?

Comment: Proof will be done by moderator / admin. :)

Comment: i am looking for PHP Matrix data structure like in this below code, which is a binary tree in this case 
http://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i was looking for from below link. 
[http://hawkee.com/snippet/10086/]

for anyone who is interested in this finding out i will post it here.

There is second solution for this also using array within array. Which i will post below this,

```
<?php 
class Matrix {
    public $arr, $rows, $cols;

    function Matrix($row, $col) {
        if ($row > 0 && $col > 0) {
            $arr        = array();
            $this->rows = $row;
            $this->cols = $col;

            for ($a=0; $a < $this->rows; $a++) {
                array_push($arr,array());

                for ($b=0; $b < $this->cols; $b++) {
                    array_push($arr[$a],0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function SetElem($x, $y, $val) {
        if ($x > -1 && $x < $this->rows) {
            if ($y > -1 && $y < $this->cols) {
                $this->arr[$x][$y] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    function GetElem($x, $y) {
        if ($x > -1 && $x < $this->rows) {
            if ($y > -1 && $y < $this->cols) {
                return $this->arr[$x][$y];
            }
        }
    }

    function Add($matrix) {
        if ($this->rows == $matrix->rows && $this->cols == $matrix->cols) {
            $rslt = new Matrix($this->rows,$this->cols);

            for ($a=0; $a < $this->rows; $a++) {
                for ($b=0; $b < $this->cols; $b++) {
                    $rslt->SetElem($a,$b,$this->GetElem($a,$b) + $matrix->GetElem($a,$b));
                }
            }

            return $rslt;
        }
    }

    function Subtract($matrix) {
        if ($this->rows == $matrix->rows && $this->cols == $matrix->cols) {
            $rslt = new Matrix($this->rows,$this->cols);

            for ($a=0; $a < $this->rows; $a++) {
                for ($b=0; $b < $this->cols; $b++) {
                    $rslt->SetElem($a,$b,$this->GetElem($a,$b) - $matrix->GetElem($a,$b));
                }
            }

            return $rslt;
        }
    }

    function Multiply($matrix) {
        if ($this->cols == $matrix->rows) {
            $rslt = new Matrix($this->rows, $matrix->cols);

            for ($a=0; $a < $rslt->rows; $a++) {
                for ($b=0; $b < $rslt->cols; $b++) {
                    $total = 0;

                    for ($c=0; $c < $matrix->rows; $c++) {
                        $total += $this->GetElem($a,$c) * $matrix->GetElem($c,$b);
                    }

                    $rslt->SetElem($a,$b,$total);
                }
            }

            return $rslt;
        }
    }

    function ScalarMultiply($num) {
        $rslt = new Matrix($this->rows,$this->cols);

        for  ($a=0; $a < $rslt->rows; $a++) {
            for  ($b=0; $b < $rslt->cols; $b++) {
                $rslt->SetElem($a,$b,$this->GetElem($a,$b) * $num);
            }
        }

        return $rslt;
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
<?php include 'Matrix.php'; 
$mat = new Matrix(2,2);

$mat->SetElem(0,0,1);
$mat->SetElem(0,1,2);
$mat->SetElem(1,0,3);
$mat->SetElem(1,1,4);

$mat2 = new Matrix(2,2);

$mat2->SetElem(0,0,5);
$mat2->SetElem(0,1,6);
$mat2->SetElem(1,0,7);
$mat2->SetElem(1,1,8);

$MultiplyResult = $mat->Multiply($mat2);
$ScalarResult   = $mat->ScalarMultiply(2);
$AddResult      = $mat->Add($mat2);
$SubtractResult = $mat->Subtract($mat2);
```

second solution was to not all that good but still will do the work.

```
$graha = array
  (
  array("Sun",5,5,0,4 ... ),
  array("Moon",5,3,...),
  ... 
);
```

In this you have to keep the index[1=Sun,2=Moon,] somewhere else to find out which element it matches when requesting elements from the matrix.